# Atiyah-Macdonald Ex8.6

Tags: commutative-algebra

Is there anybody can give a proof? I can prove "finite" only, but I cannot prove "bounded".

Here is the exercise:
Let *A* be a Noetherian ring and *Q* a *P*-primary ideal in *A*. Consider chains of primary ideals from *Q* to *P*. Show that all such chains are of finite bounded length, and that all maximal chains have the same length.

Comment: Hint: consider the (primary) ideals of the ring $A_P / Q A_P$.

Comment: Dear Andrea, I've already considered this. In fact, I proved "finite" by this method. What I can't prove is "bounded", which means the bound is independt of the prime ideal _P_.

Comment: See my answer below. By the way, the lenght of maximal chains depends on the prime ideal $P$!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ a noetherian ring, let $P$ be a prime ideal of $A$ and $Q$ a $P$-primary ideal. Consider the ring $B = A_P / Q A_P$.
Prove:

1) Every ideal of $B$ is $\bar{P}$-primary.

2) There is a 1:1 correspondence between the set of $P$-primary ideals of $A$ that contain $Q$ and the set of ideals of $B$. This correspondence preserves containments.

3) $B$ is an artinian ring, so $B$ is a $B$-module of finite length.

4) Every chain of ideals of $B$ has lenght $ \leq l_B(B)$. Every maximal chain of ideals of $B$ has lenght $= l_B(B)$. ($l_B(B)$ is the length of $B$ as a $B$-module.)

Comment: Thank you. Your proof just show the finiteness. I also did this. But the exercise asks us to prove not only the finiteness, but also the boundedness. It means that there exists an integer _M_ such that _l(B)<M_ for any prime ideal of _A_. Do you agree with me?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the text of the exercise. It is false what you are saying: consider in $k[x]$ the chain $(x) \supsetneqq (x^2) \supsetneqq (x^3) \supsetneqq \cdots$.

Comment: Very elegant, Andrea. Especially 1), which eliminates any further consideration of  "primary"! *A proposito*, it might be reminded that an ideal with maximal nilradical is primary.

Comment: Thank you for your example, dear @Andrea. It make me realized that I was misinterpreting.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** Dear User, this is just to tell you that I have trimmed a bit the [Google list](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/l#!threadID=GJi4trBUNGrg%2FBDQZE3woQvueyqKAm). It contains all the solutions to the AM exercises I have been able to find on the web, but I'm sure there are many others. If you know some of these others, please add them to this community wiki answer by editing it. **TIDE**

This is **not** an answer, and this is a community wiki.

I don't know if it's a good idea, but if you're interested you can help me collect here links to online solutions to Atiyah-MacDonald exercises.

Here is my [Google list](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/l#!threadID=GJi4trBUNGrg%2FBDQZE3woQvueyqKAm) of such links.

It's very messy, and some links are broken.

If it turn out to be a bad idea, I can delete this "answer", and give the link in a comment.

Here is a MathOveflow [Errata for Atiyah-MacDonald](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42241/errata-for-atiyah-macdonald).

Comment: Do you mean this result of this exercise is false? Is there any counter examples?

Comment: Dear @Chan: No, I don't mean that. My "answer" is **not** really an answer. It has nothing to do with Exercise 8.6. It's only related to the exercises of this book **in general**. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: OK, I see. And your idea is good, I think. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Pierre-Yves, do you have any other google lists for other books?

Comment: Hi @yunone! No, sorry... (BTW I've just organized the google list. It's slightly less messy now. Thanks for your interest.) - To the other: from [yunone's MSE page](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/1583/yunone): "A hobby of mine is attempting to 'completely solve' books as I go through them. I'm currently working on the following: Herbert Enderton's Elements of Set Theory; Kenneth Ireland and Michael Rosen's Modern Number Theory..."